# Given a regular language $L$ over $\Sigma:=\{1,2,3\}$, is $Sort(L)$ context-free?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Given an ordered alphabet $\Sigma$, denote $Sort(w)$ the word obtained from $w$ when ordering the characters of $w$ ascending. For a language $L$, define $Sort(L):=\{Sort(w) | w \in L \}$.

Let $L$ be a regular language over $\Sigma:=\{1,2,3\}$. is $Sort(L)$ context-free?

I understand why it is important that $|\Sigma| \leq 2$ (otherwise, we can construct a counter-example using the pumping lemma), but I'm not sure about $\Sigma:=\{1,2,3\}$. Any clues?

Comment: In general it is NOT True. For example consider $L$ itself to be sorted. $L=\{a^nb^nc^n\}$ then by Bar-Hillel Lemma, it is not-context free.

Comment: But in this case $L$ itself is not regular. What about when $L$ is regular?

Comment: Sorry, I did not consider $L$ to be regular. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the regular language $(abc)^*$. Then $Sort(L) = \{a^nb^nc^n \mid n \geqslant 0 \}$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer as a reference for others:

Construct a CFG using a minor change (in **bold**) to [the algorithm](http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cps220/Notes/CFL.pdf) that turns a DFA into a CFG:

1. Make a variable $R_i$ for each state $q_i$ of the DFA.
2. Add the rule $R_i \rightarrow \sigma R_j$ to the CFG if there is a DFA transition with **a character** $\sigma \neq b$ from state Ri to Rj, **and a rule $R_i \rightarrow R_j b$ to the CFG if there is a DFA transition with the character b**.
3. Add the rule $R_i \rightarrow  \epsilon$ if $q_i$ is an accept state.
4. Make $R_0$ the start variable - where $q_0$ is the start state of DFA.

This constructs a CFG for Sort(L). Hence, it is context-free.

Comment: If you consider the three state dfa that generates $(abc)^*$, I can't see how your algorithm creates anything beyond variables without transitions.